# How do I get the values of a new row in a DevExpress GridView?

Tags: gridview, devexpress, windows-forms-designer, gridcontrol, devexpress-windows-ui

I'm using C#, Windows Forms, DevExpress 19.1.  I have a grid whose data source is a binding list.  I've allowed the option for the user to enter a new row of data.  After the user enters the new data, how do I get the new data?  For updates, I've used the CellValueChanged or RowUpdated events which give me a row handle and then I use that row handle to get he new values.  But when I do this on an added row, the row handle is -2147483647.

An example.  Below is my grid.  I just typed in the values in the bottom highlighted row.  How to I get the values for this row in the code?

[image]

Comment: Hi are you using INotifypropertychanged ? if yes your list (datasource) will be updated when value are changed or new value

Comment: If not look here => https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/Ticket/Details/T186471/a-new-row-is-null-in-the-gridview-rowupdated-event-handler

Answer (score 0):

Based on [ZZ Oussama's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1981457/zz-oussama) comment above, I used the Dev Express link he suggested to come up with this solution using the RowUpdated event:

```
private void gvCompanies_RowUpdated(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowObjectEventArgs e)
{
    Department newCompany = (Department)e.Row;
}
```